# Render gets called on state change, props need to be updated on child but the child does not get rerendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, rendering, web3js

I have the following code:

```
// Packages
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import Header from './components/Header';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      account: null,
      contract: null,
    }

  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
        this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((err, accounts) => {
          if(err)
              throw err;
          } else {
            this.state.web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0];
            this.contract = new this.state.web3.eth.Contract(abi.abi, this.contractAddress);
            this.setState({
              account : accounts[0],
              contract : this.contract
            });

          }
      });
    } else {
        console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (

      <div className="App">
        <Header
          account = {this.state.account}
          web3={this.state.web3}
          contract={this.state.contract}
        />          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I want the Header component to rerender if setState is complete and the render function does get called with the updated state after the setState function in componentDidMount.

If I log in my Header component it only gets called once and the props do not get updated..

```
...
    class Header extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          accountBalance: "-",
          formattedAddress: '0x0...000',
          account: '0x0'
        }

      }

      componentDidMount(){
        console.log('rendered');
      }
...
```

I'm absolutely clueless about what it is that might be going wrong..

Comment: `componentDidMount` will only be called once. Try logging in `render`.

Comment: Yes that works, thanks! Is there a event for rerendering? I would like to access my updated props without messing within the render function.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` etc. See all lifecycle here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating

Comment: Awesome thank you so much.. I was just searching in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

In your case, componentWillReceiveProps() is the suitable life cycle method to deal with the updated prop values. You can read about this here:
https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1

Comment: This will soon be deprecated, and `getDerivedStateFromProps()` should be used instead.